# Goldberg-Seymour conjecture

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I am wondering whether the graph theory community regards the Goldberg-Seymour conjecture as settled. According to the [Wikipedia entry on the Goldberg-Seymour conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg%E2%80%93Seymour_conjecture), "In 2019, an alleged proof was announced by Chen, Jing, and Zang." As far as I can tell, the arXiv preprint of Chen, Jing, and Zang remains unpublished. Have any established graph theorists given it a careful reading and deemed it free of gaps and errors?

Comment: I believe that [MO policy](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/942) is to avoid asking these types of questions.

Comment: MO strikes me as an eminently suitable forum for questions like mine. A lack of replies to such a question should not be interpreted as signifying anything at all, but a reply that directs the community’s attention toward a specific gap in a proof (perhaps a gap known to an in-group but not to the mathematical community at large) could be useful in directing more attention to that gap. And a reply that says “I spent a semester going through the article with some grad students in meticulous detail and it seems solid” could be useful in a different way.

Comment: Whether this type of question is suitable for MO is probably best discussed on meta.MO. This meta-question has come up repeatedly before, and a quasi-consensus has been reached. Given this state of affairs, I'd recommend going with the quasi-consensus *unless* you feel that that quasi-consensus should be revisited, in which case meta.MO is right forum for arguing your case.

Comment: I’ve said this before, but I’m with Jim in favoring allowing these kind of questions. Of course we do not want “this preprint claiming to solve the RH was posted to the arXiv last night, is it right?” type questions; but when the status of a significant problem in some area is genuinely in doubt because of a long-standing claimed solution, MO is a better venue than informal word-of-mouth for establishing community consensus.